# Pass routing params to element

Tags: polymer, polymer-starter-kit

The [polymer-starter-kit](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit) uses a `<section>` when displaying routing params, like this:

```
<section data-route="user-info">
  <paper-material elevation="1">
    <h2 class="page-title">User: {{params.name}}</h2>
    <div>This is {{params.name}}'s section</div>
  </paper-material>
</section>
```

But I would like to pass the `params.name` data to an element, like this:

```
<notification-section params="{{params}}" data-route="notifications"></notification-section>
```

While I can pass the data to the element and stamp it out in its template there's no way for me to access to `params` variable from any [lifecycle events](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#lifecycle-callbacks) (such as `ready` for example).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access params from the "attached" callback like so

```
Polymer({
  is: 'notification-section',
  properties: {
    params: {
      type: Object,
    },
  },
  attached: function(e) {
    console.log('params', this.params);
  },
});
```

You can read more about the attached event [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#initialization-order)

I also have a working demo [here](http://jsbin.com/qumoba/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: As far as I understand it, at the time of `ready` or `attached` lifecycle events (of `notification-section`) the parent element has not yet been created. Any dynamically set properties will not be ready in the child (`notification-section`).

Comment: Testing this in my code shows that params is undefined.

Comment: Sorry I thought you meant like [this](http://jsbin.com/qumoba/edit?html,js,console,output). Are you setting the attribute on the parent element, which is passed to the child element, and trying to read it from one of the child elements lifecycle events? If not I misunderstood the question sorry.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. But this is not working in my code. I have to look in to it -I'll get back to you.

Comment: Is there anything else you can tell me about your code, Including browser, polymer version, and structure of your main file which is importing the elements? If I can get my demo as close as possible to your code I might be able to better find out what's going on.

Comment: I might publish an alpha version of the site somewhere so others can help me come up with a good solution. But your answer might be the correct one, along with some additions. I'll get back to you when I have figured it out.

Comment: I edited the answer so that the params property is initialized to empty object. This can potentially solve your problem @RyanWhite

Answer (score 0):

Being the elements are prepared from deepest child up, the `ready` event won't have access to data that is set my ascending components.  If you're wanting to make functional changes to your element based on that data, you'll either need to bind to the `changed` event instead or think about a different way of initializing that element that what is supported out of the box by `iron-pages`.

Comment: I think you're correct. I am looking at alternatives -perhaps `iron-meta`.

Comment: @Mike you could wrap the child element in a `dom-if` and only instantiate it when `params.name` is available and then it would be there. Slight processing overhead bump, but if you really need that param in the lifecycle events, that should get it there for you. I wonder what you're trying to get at by having that available at those times, the example you give in the question would seem not to benefit from that, but I'm sure it's just a distillation of the larger issues at hand.